# Python search filenames in subfolders using regex and append to list for further use

Tags: regex, list, search, python-2.6, subdirectory

My file system contains a large number of folders, with the folder names in the format of 4 digits. Within each folder are varying numbers of files in different formats, with names corresponding to the folder name, some with letters and/or dates appended to it. What I would like to do is search through each folder and if a year in the format "19??" or "20??" is found, create a folder labelled with that year. If the filename further contains the expression "ED*", create a subfolder with that label. Once all the folders are created, copy all files into their corresponding folders, and strip the names down to the first 6 characters. This file structure will be created on a separate drive.

Example: The folder MAIN contains many subfolders such as 2742, 2830, 3417 etc. The folder 2742 contains the files

- 2742AB.txt
- 2742AB_1999.tif
- 2742BB_1999_ED1.txt
- 2742AC_1999_ED2_FINAL.txt
- 2742CC_2001_ED4.tif

After  running the script, the folder structure should be  as follows:

- MAIN\2742\2742AB.txt
- MAIN\2742\1999\2742AB.tif
- MAIN\2742\1999\ED1\2742BB.txt
- MAIN\2742\1999\ED2\2742AC.txt
- MAIN\2742\2001\ED4\2742CC.tif

Using various snippets of code after searching for similar examples on here, I have come up with the following:
    import os
    folder = 'C:\MAIN'
    os.chdir(folder)

```
dirlist = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        dirlist.append(subdirname)
    for filename in filenames:
        dirlist.append(filename)
```

My problem is the next part, i.e amending the above search to check first if the value is already in the list. If it is in the list, continue searching, else check if the filename contains the regex and if it does, add it to the array. In (sort of) psuedocode:

```
initialise list years
#search through folders etc
for filenames in folders
    if filename contains either regex
        for values in years
            if filename exists
                skip it and continue searching
            else
                append filename to years
```

I've looked at the various answers on here about searching folders using a regex etc, but I'm not entirely sure if the approach I am using is correct. Any advice and/or comments on the approach I have used would be appreciated.

**edit** My edited code, using Michal's suggestions below and modifying it a bit myself:

```
import os, re, shutil
tfolder = 'C:\\MAIN'
os.chdir(tfolder)

re_year19xx = re.compile('(19[0-9][0-9])')
re_year20xx = re.compile('(20[0-9][0-9])')
re_ed = re.compile('(ed[0-9]\d+)', re.IGNORECASE)
destPath = 'C:\\DEST'

filePath, coords = os.path.split(fname)
coordsFolder = coords[:4]
coordsFname = coords[:6]
coordsExt = os.path.splitext(fname)
year = ' ' #create variable year
ed = ' ' #create variable ed to store the edition number if necessary
bname = fname #the original file name
for re_year in (re_year19xx, re_year20xx):
    rx = re_year.search(fname) #search for regex in the file name and store it in rx
    if rx:
        year = rx.group(1) #if the regex is found, store the year
        print(year)
        bname.replace(year, ' ')
        re_searchEd = re_ed.search(fname)
        if re_searchEd:
            ed = re_searchEd.group(1)
            bname.replace(ed, ' ')
    os.chdir(destPath)  
    fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder,year, ed) + coordsFname + coordsExt[1]
    print('%s -> %s' % (fname, fname2))
    dirn, _ = os.path.split(fname2)
    if not os.path.exists(dirn):
        os.makedirs(dirn)
    shutil.copy(fname, fname2)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tfolder):
    for name in files:
        fn = os.path.join(root, name)
        analyse_file_name(fn)
```

Looking at my code again, everything seems to be working correctly until it must create the subfolders i.e. once the `coordsFolder` has been created, if `year` is not blank, create subfolders, if `ed` is not blank, create subfolders, then copy the original files to the respective subfolders and rename. The result of the debug `print` statement for the folder `2742` is as follows:

```
C:\MAIN\2742\2742AB.txt -> C:\DEST\2742\year\ed2742AB.txt
C:\MAIN\2742\2742AB.txt -> C:\DEST\2742\year\ed2742AB.txt
1999
C:\MAIN\2742\2742AB_1999.tif -> C:\DEST\2742\1999\ed2742AB.tif
C:\MAIN\2742\2742AB_1999.tif -> C:\DEST\2742\1999\ed2742AB.tif
1999
C:\MAIN\2742\2742AC_1999_ED2_final.tif -> C:\DEST\2742\1999\ed2742AC.tif
C:\MAIN\2742\2742AC_1999_ED2_final.tif -> C:\DEST\2742\1999\ed2742AC.tif
1999
C:\MAIN\2742\2742BB_1999_ED1.txt -> C:\DEST\2742\1999\ed2742BB.txt
C:\MAIN\2742\2742BB_1999_ED1.txt -> C:\DEST\2742\1999\ed2742BB.txt
C:\MAIN\2742\2742CC_2001_ED4.tif -> C:\DEST\2742\year\ed2742CC.tif
2001
C:\MAIN\2742\2742CC_2001_ED4.tif -> C:\DEST\2742\2001\ed2742CC.tif
1999
```

**edit** After adding in a check for the value of `year`:

```
if year is 'year':
    fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder) + '\\' + coordsFname + coordsExt[1]
else:
    fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder,year) + '\\' + coordsFname + coordsExt[1]
```

The paths are npw created correctly and the files are being copied over to the correct places and renamed properly! So the last part of the question now applies to the `ed` subfolders. At the moment, the code is just ignoring the part of the filename that has "ED1", "ED2" etc in it. Where do I place the code to create the subfolders if the value of `ed` is not the initial value of "ed">

Comment: I just realised that for those files which don't have a year or edition in it's name, that of course `year` and `ed` is going to be blank. The above code still tries to create the folders though (with blank names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer to my question (after much editing and lots of help from @Michal Niklas:

```
import os, re, shutil

tfolder = 'C:\\MAIN'

os.chdir(tfolder)

re_year19xx = re.compile('(19[0-9][0-9])')
re_year20xx = re.compile('(20[0-9][0-9])')

re_ed = re.compile('(ED[0-9])')
destPath = 'C:\\DEST'

def analyse_file_name(fname):
    filePath, coords = os.path.split(fname) #the new folders will be named according to the first 4 characters of the original file name
    coordsFolder = coords[:4]
    coordsFname = coords[:6]
    coordsExt = os.path.splitext(fname)
    year = 'year' #create variable year
    ed = 'ed' #create variable ed to store the edition number if necessary
    bname = fname #the original file name
        for re_year in (re_year19xx, re_year20xx):
        rx = re_year.search(fname) #search for regex in the file name and store it in rx
        if rx:
            year = rx.group(1) #if the regex is found, store the year
            bname.replace(year, ' ')
            res = re_ed.search(fname)
            if res:
                ed = res.group(1)
                bname.replace(ed, ' ')
        os.chdir(destPath)  
        if year is 'year':
            fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder) + '\\' + coordsFname + coordsExt[1]
        else:
            fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder,year,ed) + '\\' + coordsFname + coordsExt[1]
        print('%s -> %s' % (fname, fname2)) #debug print
        dirn, _ = os.path.split(fname2)
        if not os.path.exists(dirn):
            os.makedirs(dirn)
        shutil.copy(fname, fname2)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tfolder):
    for name in files:
        fn = os.path.join(root, name)
        analyse_file_name(fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create function that analyze file name -- splits its parts, replaces them with things you want to etc. Example of such function:

```
re_year19xx = re.compile('(19\d\d)')
re_year20xx = re.compile('(20\d\d)')

re_ed = re.compile('(ed\d+)', re.IGNORECASE)


def analyze_file_name(fname):
    digits = fname[:4]
    year = ''
    ed = ''
    bname = fname
    for re_year in (re_year19xx, re_year20xx):
        rx = re_year.search(fname)
        if rx:
            year = rx.group(1)
            bname = bname.replace(year, '')
    rx = re_ed.search(fname)
    if rx:
        ed = rx.group(1)
        bname = bname.replace(ed, '')
    fname2 = os.path.join('MAIN', digits, year, ed, bname)
    fname2 = fname2.replace('_', '')
    print('%s -> %s' % (fname, fname2))
```

If you want to move (rename) file to new destination, then you can check & create destination directory and then move file there. Code can look like:

```
    ...
    fname2 = fname2.replace('_', '')
    dirn, _ = os.path.split(fname2)
    if not os.path.exists(dirn):
        os.makedirs(dirn)
    os.rename(fname, fname2)
    print('%s -> %s' % (fname, fname2))
```

Instead of `os.rename()` you can use `shutil.copy()` if you want to have both source and destination file.

You have also problem with `os.walk()`. In current form you will get the same file name many times and `analyze_file_name()` will get only last part of file name (ie. without directory). I will show you how you can get full file name:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tfolder):
    for name in files:
        fn = os.path.join(root, name)
        analyse_file_name(fn)
```

You can also add extra parameter with dir name to `analyse_file_name()`.

Full version based on your last source with creating dest directory:

```
def analyse_file_name(fname):
    filePath, coords = os.path.split(fname)
    coordsFolder = coords[:4]
    coordsFname = coords[:6]
    coordsExt = os.path.splitext(fname)
    year = 'year' #create variable year
    ed = 'ed' #create variable ed to store the edition number if necessary
    bname = fname #the original file name
    for re_year in (re_year19xx, re_year20xx):
        rx = re_year.search(fname) #search for regex in the file name and store it in rx
        if rx:
            year = rx.group(1) #if the regex is found, store the year
            print(year)
            bname.replace(year, ' ')
            re_searchEd = re_ed.search(fname)
            if re_searchEd:
                ed = re_searchEd.group(1)
                bname.replace(ed, ' ')
        fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder,year, ed)
        fname2 = fname2 + coordsFname + coordsExt[1]
        print('%s -> %s' % (fname, fname2))
        dirn, _ = os.path.split(fname2)
        if not os.path.exists(dirn):
            os.makedirs(dirn)
        shutil.copy(fname, fname2)
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion (please see my edited question above), it runs but doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `fname2` is destination file. Do not make such directory. You can split path and file name using function from `os.path` module. Then create directory you want, and move/copy file to new name. Make backup first :)

Comment: I've added in the following two lines:    `newDir = os.path.split(fname2)` and `os.mkdir(newDir.head + '\\' + year)`. It runs, but nothing happens.

Comment: Please see my edited question above. I just realised, should I not have a variable specifying the destination for the new folder structure?

Comment: Remove one tab before `shutil.copy()`. As for variable with destination then it is combination of `tfolder` and parts of file name. This is saved in `dirn`.

Comment: I've tried that, but it still doesn't work. I really can't see where the problem could be?

Comment: So you must add some debug prints to see if program tries to create dir or tries to copy file. Then you can show output.

Comment: I've changed my function call to `for filename in os.walk(tfolder):analyse_file_name(filename)` and realised that it wasn't even calling the function before, it just walked through the folders and terminated. Now at the line `rx = re_year.search(fname)` it gives a `TypeError: expected string or buffer`.

Comment: I did have something similar initially, so I reverted to my previous version of `os.walk()` and added in your `join` line. The code breaks at `shutil.copy(fname2, dirn)`, with the error "Source and destination are the same".

Comment: In my edited answer you will see full `analyse_file_name()` based on your last source with creating dest directory

Comment: It almost works! The directories are created correctly, with subfolders for the years it extracts from the regular expressions. However, for the files which don't have a year e.g. `2742ab.txt`, it should copy that into the root folder `2742`. Instead it creates a `year` subfolder and places it in there. It also doesn't create subfolders within the `year` subfolders according to the value of `ed` e.g. `2742BB.txt` is in folder `2742\\1999` when it should be in `2742\\1999\\ED1`.

Comment: This line `fname2 = os.path.join(destPath, coordsFolder,year, ed)` appears to be appending "ed" at the start of each new filename. When I remove `ed`, "year" is appended. If I remove `year`, the value of `coordsFolder` is appended and so on. Does this mean that `os.path.join` is unnecessary in this instance, since I am building the new file name up by concatenating several variables, and then renaming the file with this string once the respective folders have been created?

Comment: Removing `os.path.join` throws an error as it cannot find the specified path, which seems obvious now that I think about it again.

Comment: please see edited question above, including output of the `print` statement.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I could not have solved this without you! I'll vote you up as soon as I get more rep :-/